# How to format unconventional output into simple json dump

Tags: python, json, kafka-python

In the answer from this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55832055/5937760

The output is:

```
{TopicPartition(topic=u'python-test', partition=0): 5,
 TopicPartition(topic=u'python-test', partition=1): 20,
 TopicPartition(topic=u'python-test', partition=2): 0}
```

When I do a `json.dumps` on it, I get this:

```
[["python-test", 0], ["python-test", 1], ["python-test", 2]]
```

How can I get it to output like so:

```
[[0,5],[1,20],[2,0]]
```

Comment: Are you using `json.dump` or `json.dumps`?

Comment: @sjking dumps, fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value looks like a dictionary, so you should be able to get its keys and values with `.items()`. Then extract the partition number from the key.

```
json.dumps([[key.partition, value] for key, value in end_offset.items()])
```

Comment: Is there an easy way I can have the output like so?
`{"0":5,"1":20,"2":0}`

Comment: `json.dumps({str(key.partion): value for key, value in end_offset.items()})`

Comment: Read up on list and dictionary comprehensions to learn how to do these things.